# Query knex with join in 3 tables

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, knex.js

I'm having trouble running the query below with the knex. I managed to make a join with two tables, but this join with 3 tables where the vehicle element id is = x, I am not getting it.

Below follows sql query and the way I tried with the knex, without success.

Thank you very much in advance!

```sql
SELECT v.id   AS id_veiculo, 
       v.placa, 
       v.marca, 
       v.exibicao, 
       v.modelo, 
       v.renavam, 
       v.chassi, 
       v.ano_fabri, 
       v.ano_modelo, 
       v.id_combustivel, 
       v.capacidade_litros, 
       v.cor, 
       v.uf_placa, 
       v.status, 
       t.id   AS id_servico, 
       t.servico, 
       c.nome AS combustivel 
FROM   veiculo v 
       INNER JOIN tipo_servico_veiculo tsv 
               ON tsv.veiculo_id = v.id 
                  AND v.id = :id 
       INNER JOIN tipo_servico t 
               ON t.id = tsv.servico_id 
       INNER JOIN combustivel c 
               ON c.id = v.id_combustivel
```

knex, version: "^0.21.2"

```js
const result = await knex('veiculo as v')
  .join('tipo_servico_veiculo as tsv', function () {
    this.on('tsv.veiculo_id', '=', 'v.id').andOn('v.id', '=', id);
  })
  .join('tipo_servico t', 't.id', '=', 'tsv.servico_id')
  .join('combustivel as c', 'v.id_combustivel', '=', 'c.id')
  .select(
    'v.id',
    'v.placa',
    'v.marca',
    'v.exibicao',
    'v.modelo',
    'v.cor',
    'v.status',
    'c.nome as combustivel',
    't.servico'
  );
```

Comment: Your knex statment looks fine to me, what is the issue? did you tried to add `.debug()` at the end in order to debug the built query?

Comment: Thanks for the tip, @felixmosh! 

one way that worked was this:

const result = await knex('cnh as c')
                .join('categoria_cnh as cat', 'c.categoria_id', '=', 'cat.id')
                .join('motorista as m', 'c.motorista_id', '=', 'm.id')
                .where('c.id', '=', id)
                .select('c.numero', 'c.vencimento', 'cat.id as categoria_id', 'cat.categoria',
                    'm.id as motorista_id', 'm.exibicao');